# Receiving invalid image format error with NodeJS Rekognition api call

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I'm trying to make a call to the Amazon Rekognition service with NodeJS. The call is going through but I receive an `InvalidImageFormatException` error in which it says:

> Invalid Input, input image shouldn't be empty.

I'm basing my code off an S3 example:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var rekognition = new AWS.Rekognition({region: 'us-east-1'});

//Create a bucket and upload something into it

var params = {
    Image: {
        S3Object: {
            Bucket: "MY-BUCKET-NAME",
            Name: "coffee.jpg"
        }
    },
    MaxLabels: 10,
    MinConfidence: 70.0
};

var request = rekognition.detectLabels(params, function(err, data) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occured
    } 
    else{
        console.log(data);               // successful response
    }
});
```

The documentation states that the service only accepts PNG or JPEG images but I can't figure out what is going on.

Comment: Perhaps it is guessing the image type based on the extension - i.e. .jpg vs. .jpeg.

Comment: Just changed the file extension and noticed that the previous file I uploaded was 0 bytes. This file actually had data associated with it the call to the service worked. Thank you!